# How to embed a real player in a page to play it into Firefox and Google Chrome

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, embed

I am developing a website, i need to play a video in my site so i used embed tag. As my video is based on real player file format. So i need to play it with real player,i found a way to play in IE, but i want mainly in Firefox and chrome. can anyone please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free component to add the video to your site:

[ASPNetVideo Component](http://pcwin.com/Software_Development/ASPNetVideo/index.htm)

After installing it you need to drop the control on the page and set VideoURL property of the Video control to the correct video location.

Comment: What exactly do you need then?